# Is there an alternative to bs4's find_all() method that returns another soup object instead of a list, for further navigation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Upon finding all the `<ul>`'s, I'd like to further extract the text, and the `href`'s. The problem I'm facing particular to this bit of HTML, is that I need most, but not all the `<li>` items in the page. I see that when I `find_all()`, I am returned a list object which does not allow me to further navigate it as a soup object.
For example, in the below snippet, to ultimately create a dictionary of `{'cityName': 'href',}`, I have tried:

```
city_list = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': ''})
city_dict = {}
for city in city_list:
    city_dict[city.text] = city['href']
```

Here is the sample minimal HTML:

```
<h4>Alabama</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://auburn.craigslist.org/">auburn</a></li>
<li><a href="https://bham.craigslist.org/">birmingham</a></li>
<li><a href="https://tuscaloosa.craigslist.org/">tuscaloosa</a></li>
</ul>
<h4>Alaska</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://anchorage.craigslist.org/">anchorage / mat-su</a></li>
<li><a href="https://juneau.craigslist.org/">southeast alaska</a></li>
</ul>
<h4>Arizona</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://flagstaff.craigslist.org/">flagstaff / sedona</a></li>
<li><a href="https://yuma.craigslist.org/">yuma</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/">help</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.craigslist.org/about/scams">safety</a></li>
<li class="fsel mobile linklike" data-mode="regular">desktop</li>
</ul>
```

How can I, essentially, `find_all()` the `ul`'s first, and then further find only the `li`'s that interest me?

Comment: `for ul in soup.find_all('ul'): # do something with ul that is a soup object to find what you want...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
city_dict = {}
for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    city_name = li.text
    for link in li.find_all('a'):
        city_dict[city_name] = link['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like this:

```
city_dict = {}
for ul in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': ''}):
    state_name = ul.find_previous_sibling('h4').text
    print(state_name)
    for link in ul.find_all('a'):
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: I don't think Arizona goes with the safety information :)

Comment: It's just an example which you need to elaborate yourself :)

Comment: Could just do: `{h4.string: {a.string: a['href'] for a in h4.find_next('ul').select('li a')} for h4 in soup.select('h4')}` depending on the nuances of the structure...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Thank me later :)

```
list_items = soup.find_all('ul',{'class':''})
list_of_dicts = []
for item in list_items:
    for i in item.find_all('li'):
        new_dict = {i.text:i.a.get('href')}
        list_of_dicts.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: Presumably you mean `for i in item.find_all` there?

Comment: @ Jon Clements  Yes.. Sorry for the typo... :)